# Space appearing between divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this issue where a space is appearing between two divs and I don't know what is causing this. Basically it is just one div with three smaller divs of fixed height inside of it. The space is between the `block-title` and `block-content` divs. There is no space between the `block-content` and `block-footer`

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="block buy">
  <div class="block-title">
    <span class="line-1">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-content">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="block-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.block {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
}
.block-title {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.block-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 255px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block-footer {
  height: 75px;
}
.block-title,
.block-content,
.block-footer {
  color: #fff;
}
.line-1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}
.buy > * {
  background-color: #558F38;
}
```

A live JSfiddle is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opx8ja75/17/)

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Edit**

So the reason why the space appears is because the `<h2>` elements margin goes outside of the containing div. Why is it not contained inside the div?

Comment: check your <h2></h2> the issues is coming from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your h2 has margin that escapes its container and pushes the outer divs. Remove the h2 or remove its margin.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. But why is the margin of `<h2>` going out of the containing `<div>`?

Comment: This is the only post that actually answers the question.

Comment: Margins sometimes behave counter-intuitively, you can find out more about these quirks from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

In your example the margin needed to push off something, it doesn't touch the parent divs, but siblings/uncles etc are all valid to push from and cause the behaviour you saw.

Comment: @martin36 Also Google for "collapsing margins".

Comment: Thanks, I will do that

Answer (score 0):

add this class or remove

from second div

```
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.block {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
}
.block-title {
    height: 70px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.block-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    text-align: center;
}
.block-footer {
    height: 75px;
}
.block-title, .block-content, .block-footer {
    color: #fff;
}
.line-1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
}
.buy > * {
    background-color: #558F38;
}
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block buy">
  <div class="block-title">
    <span class="line-1">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block-content">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="block-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is why, not how to fix it.

Comment: @rob h2 has margin that escapes its container and pushes the outer divs.

Comment: Yes. I know that. You should have put that in your answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @rob but only you want to know "Why ?"

Comment: You didn't read the question. The question asks why, not how to fix it.

Comment: @Rob Gestures is more than enough for a wise man

Answer (score -1):

U can replace display: inline-block with display: inline-grid. Thath solves the problem.

```css
.block {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-grid;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: The question is why, not how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Why does that work and not `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score -1):

In you css you could add:

```
h2{
     margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: The question is why, not how to fix it.